# How do I make Vim ignore a backslash inside text content?

Tags: linux, vim, vi

I'm just starting out with Vim (and love it so far) so please bear with me...

I'm editing a web.config file and need to delete the value between double quotes. Normally I would use di" for this task, but the last character inside the double quotes is a backslash and thus it seems that Vim interprets it as an escape character for the succeeding quote.

I.e. in the string:

```
<add key="MyPath" value="C:\Apps\Site\" />
```

Setting the cursor above "MyPath" and hitting di" works as expected. Setting it above the path value does not... Is there some setting that handles this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear the quote escape character:

```
:set quoteescape=
```

From there, `di"` on your second attribute works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Placing the cursor above `C` and doing a `dt"` should work. `dt` deletes upto (not including) the following character.

Comment: Agreed. `quoteescape` can be quite useful in other scenarios. This scenario should be the exception, not `quoteescape`.